# MvvmCross - Safe Database in Wpf

Tags: wpf, sqlite, mvvmcross

I'm developing a Wpf application using MvvmCross. I want to protect the database. I'm using the Sqlite plugin (old version), but could not find a way to do this. I saw that it is possible to set a password in the System.Data.SQLite using the method:

```
myconnection.ChangePassword("myPassword");
```

And using the connection string:

```
"Data Source=filename;Version=3;Password=myPassword;"
```

I could not find a way to do this with the plugin. Is there a simple way to do this? Such as substituting the ConnectionFactory? Or using something that is already available?

If this is not feasible with the plugin, what would be other options? Write my own plugin using the System.Data.SQLite?

Thanks